# How to exclude directories from ArrayList<File>?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with directories and files. I need filtering it and get ArrayList with files only:

```
ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
list.add(new File("/sdcard/dir1/"));
list.add(new File("/sdcard/file1.txt"));
list.add(new File("/sdcard/file2.jpeg"));
list.add(new File("/sdcard/dir2/"));

// Filter directories here (???)

// ArrayList after: [/sdcard/file1.txt, /sdcard/file2.jpeg]
```

How to filter ArrayList?

Comment: if its just an String so why use Arraylist<File> use Arraylist<String>

Comment: u need to filter with name or check whether it is directory or file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate all elements of `ArrayList` and check if element is `File`.

Like below

```
int sizeOfList = list.size(); 
ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
for (int position = 0; position < sizeOfList; position++) {
    if (list.get(position).isFile()) {
        fileList.add(list.get(position)); 
    }
}
list = fileList;
```

Now fileList contains only those elements which are files.

---

***If you want to remove `File` from original `List` (Without using temp `List`), use below code***

```
int sizeOfList = list.size(); 
for (int position = 0; position < sizeOfList; position++) {
    if (! list.get(position).isFile()) { //OR list.get(position).isDirectory()
        list.remove(position); 
        position = position - 1;
        sizeOfList = sizeOfList - 1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check updated answer, if you don't want to use temporary List. And please update me if it works for your case. I checked it with String Arraylist and its working fine...

Answer (score 1):

Just use [isFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()) method to distinguish between normal files and directories.
Also look at the similiar [isDirectory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) method.